# SQL show the same column multiple times

Tags: mysql, pivot

Table 1 has, the NameId, age, gender...
Table 2 has Version No, TimeStamp ...

Now I want to select the NameId from Table 1, and Version No. and Timestamp multiple times from table 2, i need to query all the Version and Time records from table2, 
can anyone give me some idea about how to query?

```
NameId  |   Version/Time        |   Version/Time    |   Version/Time …

Angela  |    1  /  01.01.2010   |   2 / 01.02.2010  |   3 / 01.03.2010
Betty   |    1  /  01.01.2010   |   2 / 01.02.2010  |   3 / 01.03.2010
Cathy   |    1  /  01.01.2010   |   2 / 01.02.2010  |   3 / 01.03.2010
...     |   ....                |                   |
```

Comment: Are these tables related? Or are you just trying to smoosh them together like a UNION?

Comment: @L Hebe Can you show us some schema for both of these table? I mean what is the relation between these two tables.

Comment: Can you post the table structure and some data from both tables?  Also what database are you using?  MySql, sql server, oracle?

Answer (score 0):

if, as you say, any fixed value set won't work, then you'll need dynamic sql to do your pivot.

something along these lines:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_pivot_]
AS

DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(versionTime as varchar) + ']',
'[' + cast(versionTime as varchar)+ ']')
FROM table1 inner join table2 on table1.NameId = table2.NameId
GROUP BY versionTime 

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)

SET @query = '
SELECT *
FROM table1 inner join table2 on table1.NameId = table2.NameId
PIVOT
(
first(versionTime)
FOR [versionTime]
IN (' + @columns + ')
)
AS p'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: Oh,forgot to mention, table1.NameId = table2.NameId

Comment: I mean you won't know how many versions and time I would have in table2, cuz i can insert new data anytime, so any fixed value select won't work! :)

Comment: Hey,Beth, thanks a lot for your post, since im using the MySQL as my database, can you please just point me the query part? but not the whole procesure!

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is performing a JOIN between the two tables, e.g.

```
SELECT t1.NameId
     , t2.VersionNo
     , t2.Timestamp
  FROM table_one t1
  LEFT
  JOIN table_two t2
    ON t2.NameId = t1.NameId
 ORDER
    BY t1.NameId
     , t2.VersionNo
```

That will get you a result set like:

```
NameId   VersionNo TimeStamp
-------- --------- ----------
Angela   1         01.01.2010   
Angela   2         01.02.2010  
Angela   3         01.03.2010
Betty    1         01.01.2010   
Betty    2         01.02.2010  
Betty    3         01.03.2010
Cathy    1         01.01.2010   
Cathy    2         01.02.2010  
Cathy    3         01.03.2010
```

(This assumes that `table_two` is related to `table_one` by the NameId value. The sample data provided in the original question leaves open the possibility that this is three rows in `table_two` matched with each row in `table_one` (i.e. a Cartesian product).  In that case, it would be a CROSS JOIN in the statement:

```
SELECT t1.NameId
     , t2.VersionNo
     , t2.Timestamp
  FROM table_one t1
 CROSS
  JOIN table_two t2
 ORDER
    BY t1.NameId
     , t2.VersionNo
```

---

To get the resultset from that query converted into a "crosstab" (or pivot table), with each separate row from `table_two` displayed in the same line of output, that is usually better handled in the client, rather than in the SQL statement.

However, it is possible for MySQL to return a similar resultset, with each VersionNo and Timestamp value in a separate column; but the query to do that is non-trivial.

(One trivial alternative is to use the GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function, but that returns a single column, not separate columns, and is limited by `max_allowd_packet_size`.)

```
SELECT t1.NameID
     , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t2.VersionNo,'/',t2.Timestamp) ORDER BY t2.VersionNo)
  FROM table_one t1
  LEFT
  JOIN table_two t2
    ON t2.NameId = t1.NameId
 GROUP
    BY t1.NameId
 ORDER
    BY t1.NameId
```

---

Again assuming that `table_two` is related to `table_one`, one rather unwieldy, but easily understandable, approach is to use correlated subqueries in the SELECT list of the query, e.g.

```
SELECT t1.NameId
     , ( SELECT CONCAT(t2a.VersionNo,' / ',t2a.Timestamp)
           FROM table_two t2a WHERE t2a.NameId = t1.NameID
          ORDER BY t2a.VersionNo LIMIT 0,1 
       ) AS `Version/Time`
     , ( SELECT CONCAT(t2b.VersionNo,' / ',t2b.Timestamp)
           FROM table_two t2b WHERE t2b.NameId = t1.NameID
          ORDER BY t2b.VersionNo LIMIT 1,1 
       ) AS `Version/Time`
     , ( SELECT CONCAT(t2c.VersionNo,' / ',t2c.Timestamp)
           FROM table_two t2c WHERE t2c.NameId = t1.NameID
          ORDER BY t2c.VersionNo LIMIT 2,1
       ) AS `Version/Time`
  FROM table_one t1
 ORDER BY t1.NameId
```

That query will return a resultset similar to the one shown in the original question, although the number of columns returned is statically defined within SELECT the statement.

Comment: Hey,Thanks for your idea, one thing is the amount of the versionNo and time is not knowning, just wonder how can i keep them as not fixed 1,2,3 ??

Comment: @L Hebe: the SQL SELECT statement specifies the columns to be returned; it's a fixed number, there's no way (that I know of) to make that dynamic, other than dynamically creating a SQL statement that returns the number of columns you need.  A better bet is to return a "dynamic" number of rows, and have the client process however many rows are returned. That's the normative pattern for SQL programming.